# Streaming in and out a text file in C++

Tags: c++

Basically, I'm trying to stream in a text file and stream out THE SAME information to another text file.

However, it's giving me weird new lines.

Example txt to test:

```
testing this is a test to see if this actually works

hopefully!
test



test 

test
```

This is the output it gives me after testing:

```
testing this is a test to see if this actually works
hopefully!test


test 
test
```

I want the output to be the same as the input. But I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Been stuck on this for a few hours now, lol.

Here is my code:

```
string input, name, content;
cout << "Enter input name and extension (Example: hi.txt)\n";
cin >> input;

ifstream file (input.c_str());

if (file.is_open()) {
    cout << "Enter output name and extension (Example: hi2.txt)\n";
    cin >> name;

    ofstream output(name.c_str());

    while (getline(file, content)) {
        output << content;

        if (content == "") {
            output << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `if (content == "\n")`?

Comment: Instead of using `getline()` to do it line by line, consider using `get()` to read it in bigger chunks (even the whole thing at once) without worrying about newlines.

Also, you can call `getline()` as `file.getline(content)` and keep things more consistently C++-ish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::getline` ignores the delimiter, which by default is `\n` when it reads a line. So, when it reads

```
testing this is a test to see if this actually works\n
```

`content` will actually be

```
testing this is a test to see if this actually works
```

Note the missing newline. That's why there is one new line missing after every line :)

You have to add that discarded delimiter:

```
output << content << '\n'; //Adds the discarded '\n' delimiter
```

Comment: Oh! That makes sense! Very informative. Thank you! :D